# Service Bus message abandoned despite WebJobs SDK handler completed successfully

Tags: c#, azure-webjobs, azureservicebus, azure-webjobssdk

I have implemented a long running process as a WebJob using the WebJobs SDK.
The long running process is awaited because I want the result.

```
public async Task ProcessMessage([ServiceBusTrigger("queuename")] MyMessage message)
{
    await Run(message.SomeProperty); // takes several minutes
    // I want to do something with the result here later..
}
```

What I can't figure out is why the message <s>sometimes</s> is abandoned which of course triggers the handler again. I've tried to debug (locally), setting breakpoints before `ProcessMessage` finishes and I can see that it appears to finish successfully.

The Sevice Bus part of the WebJobs SDK takes care of message lock renewal, so that shouldn't be a problem as far as I've understood.

What am I missing and how do I troubleshoot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Edited previously incorrect response]

The WebJobs SDK relies on the automatic lock renewals done by **MessageReceiver.OnMessageAsync**. These renewals are governed by the [OnMessageOptions.AutoRenewTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.onmessageoptions.autorenewtimeout.aspx) setting, which can be configured like so in the v1.1.0 release of the WebJobs SDK:

```
JobHostConfiguration config = new JobHostConfiguration();

ServiceBusConfiguration sbConfig = new ServiceBusConfiguration();
sbConfig.OnMessageOptions = new OnMessageOptions
{
  MaxConcurrentCalls = 16,
  AutoRenewTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)
};

config.UseServiceBus(sbConfig);
```

You can also customize these values via a custom **MessageProcessor**. See the [release notes here](http://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/wiki/Release-Notes) for more details on these new features.

Comment: On further investigation, while the ServiceBus documentation is very poor, it does appear that OnMessageAsync does do automatic renewals. Try configuring the **OnMessageOptions.AutoRenewTimeout** value and increase it for your scenarios. See the ServiceBus documentation on that setting [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.onmessageoptions.autorenewtimeout.aspx). The ability to configure this was only recently added to the WebJobsSDK. See ServiceBusConfiguration.OnMessageOptions.

Comment: Looks like that is the way to go. Full package name for Googlers: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus 1.1.0-beta1 (Pre-release channel, that is). Thanks for the update!